# Fatal error: Call to a member function isUploaded() on a non-object

Tags: php, zend-framework, fatal-error

I'm facing an error message:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function isUploaded() on a non-object in /www/htdocs/nether/http/123factuur/application/controllers/Helpers/ImportXls.php on line 30
```

To my understanind this error message pops-up because I'm calling a method which doesn't exists in the object. But I'm sure that isUploaded() does exists.

The function `isUploaded` is defined in the class `Zend_Form_Element_File`. To check if `$xls` is an instance of the `Zend_Form_Element_File` I debugged the `$xls` variable.

```
Zend_Debug::dump($xls); //OUTPUT: object(Zend_Form_Element_File)#141 (29) {
exit;
```

Line 30 looks like this:

```
if ( $xls->isUploaded() ) {
```

The first thing I did was to check the expression value.

```
Zend_Debug::dump($xls->isUploaded()); //the output was: bool(true)
exit;
```

Then I checked the type of the `$xls` variable.

```
echo gettype($xls); //the output was object
exit;
```

I'm not fully understanding the error. Perhaps, I'm not interpreting the error message as it should be interpreted. Anyway, assistance is needed.

The code snippet:
At the controller:

```
public function importAction() {
        $form = $this->getImportFrom();
        $this->view->form = $form;
        $this->view->allowedHeaders = array();

        $this->importInvoices($form);
        $this->importInvoiceArticles($form);
        $this->importInvoiceServices($form);
        foreach ($this->_lookupIssues as $issue) {
            $this->_flashMessenger->addMessage($issue);
        }
    }


public function importInvoiceArticles($form) {
        $model = 'Invoice_article';
        $config = Zim_Properties::getConfig($model);
        $Model = new Zim_Model($model, $config->model);
        $headerMapping = array_flip(array_intersect_key($Model->getHeaders(true), array_flip($this->_allowedArticleImportHeaders)));
        $this->getHelper('ImportXls')->handleImport($form, $headerMapping, $Model->getName(), $this->_modelName, null, null, array($this, 'saveImportedArticleData'), 'invoiceArticle');
    }
```

At the helper:

```
class F2g_Helper_ImportXls extends Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract {

public function handleImport($form, $allowedHeaders, $tableName, $modelName, $onDuplicateImportCallback, $importMethod = null, $saveMethod = null, $name = 'xls') {
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $xls = $form->getElement($name);
            if ( $xls->isUploaded() ) {
               //some code
            }  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `on a non-object` means `$xls` is not an object of any class. It might be variable ...

Comment: but after `echo gettype($xlss)` it shows `object`, why is that the case?

Comment: Can you please paste the code snippet that throws this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your condition to avoid the Fatal Error :

```
if ( !empty($xls) && is_object($xls) && $xls->isUploaded() ) {
    // do your job with serenity :)
}
```

Comment: Well that works but I don't understand why.

Comment: @Julian well apparently the code you're working on is being run multiple times. The first times it works because `$xlss` really is an object (which is what you inspected). The last time it doesn't work because `$xlss` isn't an object but you aren't inspecting it so bummer.

Comment: Halayem Anis -- it's a good solution but it's worth mentioning that OP needs to check why `$xlss` isn't an object and see if there's other stuff to fix based on this.

Answer (score 3):

I'm quite sure that the handleImport() method is called multiple times, possibly inside a loop, probably with different values for the $name parameter. You echo the variable and die in order to debug it, which works perfectly if the provided value for $name is correct on the first run - but since you kill the script - you don't get any debug information about subsequent calls.

Make sure the object has that method before calling it. You can either call method_exists() or instanceof to make that determination.

Code:

```
if ($xls instanceof Zend_Form_Element_File) {
    // object of correct type - continue (preferred version)
}

// or

if (method_exists($xls, 'isUploaded')) {
    // avoids the error, but does not guarantee that 
    // other methods of the Zend_Form_Element_File exist
}
```